# Visualize the color of the point features from the variables that have been created

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a 24 feature collection consisting of several point features. I've created color variables previously to define the graph and visualize the points. However, I was hampered by the problem that when I wanted to display points on the map, it could only display 1 color. How do you define the color of the points in the 24 feature collections as having different colors?

```
var boundary = [
  ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle([115.633630, -2.333358, 115.638940, -2.337482]), {'name' : 'LSA-01'}),
  ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle([115.605056, -2.330564, 115.61189, -2.335365]), {'name' : 'LSA-02'}),
  ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle([115.605055, -2.334686, 115.608552, -2.341264]), {'name' : 'LSA-03'}),
  ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle([115.602825, -2.337258, 115.605057, -2.342247]), {'name' : 'SCM-01'}),
  ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle([115.598726, -2.342007, 115.602857, -2.345285]), {'name' : 'SCM-02'}),
  ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle([115.594787, -2.348225, 115.597531, -2.350854]), {'name' : 'SCM-03'}),
  ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle([115.575140, -2.362315 , 115.576953, -2.363883]),{'name' : 'SCM-04'})
  ];

var iup = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Rectangle([115.5527777771, -2.3249999959, 115.6461111100, -2.3737500034]))
  ]);
  
var border = ee.FeatureCollection(boundary);

// set center map
Map.centerObject(border, 14);

var COLOR = {
  RED: 'ff0000',
  GREEN: '0000ff',
  BLUE: '00ff00',
  YELLOW:'#ffff00',
  PINK: '#ffc0cb',
  BLACK: '#000000',
  PURPLE: '#800080',
  AQUA: '#00ffff'
};

//Point known locations for NDVI
var p1 = ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.57539510901834, -2.362381045840717), {'label': 'SCM_I5I6_2022-01'});
var p2 = ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.576489, -2.363431), {'label': 'SCM_I5I6_2022-02'});
var union1 = ee.FeatureCollection([p1, p2]).set({'name': 'SCM_1516_2022'});

var p3 = ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.596284, -2.349884), {'label': 'SCM_F10B_2022'});
var union2 = ee.FeatureCollection([p3]).set({'name': 'SCM_F10B_2022'});

var p4 = ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.597183, -2.349885), {'label': 'SCM_F10_2022-01'});
var p5 = ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.597184, -2.348981), {'label': 'SCM_F10_2022-02'});
var union3 = ee.FeatureCollection([p4, p5]).set({'name': 'SCM_F10_2022'});

var p6 = ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.604485, -2.341752), {'label': 'SCM_D12_2023-01'});
var p7 = ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.603486, -2.340847), {'label': 'SCM_D12_2023-02'});
var p8 = ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.604386, -2.339944), {'label': 'SCM_D12_2023-03'});
var union4 = ee.FeatureCollection([p6, p7,p8]).set({'name': 'SCM_D12_2023'});

var p9= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.604385, -2.340848), {'label': 'SCM_D12_2022'});
var union5 = ee.FeatureCollection([p9]).set({'name': 'SCM_D12_2022'});

var p10= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.604387, -2.339039), {'label': 'SCM_C12/D12_2023'});
var union6 = ee.FeatureCollection([p10]).set({'name': 'SCM_C12/D12_2023'});

var p11= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.600785, -2.344462), {'label': 'SCM_B4_2021-01'});
var p12= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.599886, -2.344461), {'label': 'SCM_B4_2021-02'});    
var p13= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.598987, -2.34446), {'label': 'SCM_B4_2021-03'});
var p14= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.601685, -2.343559), {'label': 'SCM_B4_2021-04'});
var p15= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.600786, -2.343558), {'label': 'SCM_B4_2021-05'}); 
var p16= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.602585, -2.342655), {'label': 'SCM_B4_2021-06'});
var p17= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.601686, -2.342654), {'label': 'SCM_B4_2021-07'});
var p18= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.600787, -2.342653), {'label': 'SCM_B4_2021-08'});
var union7 = ee.FeatureCollection([p11,p12,p13,p14,p15,p16,p17,p18]).set({'name': 'SCM_B4_2021'});

var p19= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.595385, -2.349884), {'label': 'SCM_B3D_2019'});
var union8 = ee.FeatureCollection([p19]).set({'name': 'SCM_B3D_2019'});

var p20= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.596285, -2.34898), {'label': 'SCM_B1_2015-01'});
var p21= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.595085, -2.348979), {'label': 'SCM_B1_2015-02'});
var union9 = ee.FeatureCollection([p20,p21]).set({'name': 'SCM_B1_2015'});

var p22= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.606186, -2.338137), {'label': 'LSA_D1_2023-01'});
var p23= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.605287, -2.338136), {'label': 'LSA_D1_2023-02'}); 
var union10 = ee.FeatureCollection([p22,p23]).set({'name': 'LSA_D1_2023'});

var p24= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.605284, -2.340849), {'label': 'LSA_D1_2022-01'});
var p25= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.605285, -2.339945), {'label': 'LSA_D1_2022-02'}); 
var p26= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.605286, -2.33904), {'label': 'LSA_D1_2022-03'}); 
var union11 = ee.FeatureCollection([p24,p25,p26]).set({'name': 'LSA_D1_2022'});

var p27= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.638559, -2.334551), {'label': 'LSA_C8_2022-01'});
var p28= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.63766, -2.33455), {'label': 'LSA_C8_2022-02'}); 
var union12 = ee.FeatureCollection([p27,p28]).set({'name': 'LSA_C8_2022'});

var p29= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.634062, -2.335451), {'label': 'LSA_C7A_2022-01'});
var union13 = ee.FeatureCollection([p29]).set({'name': 'LSA_C7A_2022'});

var p30= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.635285, -2.337231), {'label': 'LSA_C7_2023-01'});
var union14 = ee.FeatureCollection([p30]).set({'name': 'LSA_C7_2023'});

var p31= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.63586, -2.336357), {'label': 'LSA_C7/C8_2023-01'});
var p32= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.634961, -2.336356), {'label': 'LSA_C7/C8_2023-02'});
var p33= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.638558, -2.335455), {'label': 'LSA_C7/C8_2023-03'});
var p34= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.637659, -2.335454), {'label': 'LSA_C7/C8_2023-04'});
var p35= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.63676, -2.335453), {'label': 'LSA_C7/C8_2023-05'});
var union15 = ee.FeatureCollection([p31,p32,p33,p34,p35]).set({'name': 'LSA_C7/C8_2023'});

var p36= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.636761, -2.334549), {'label': 'LSA_C7-C8(B)_2022-01'});
var union16 = ee.FeatureCollection([p36]).set({'name': 'LSA_C7-C8(B)_2022'});

var p37= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.607086, -2.337233), {'label': 'LSA_C1/D1_2023-01'});
var p38= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.606187, -2.337232), {'label': 'LSA_C1/D1_2023-02'});
var p39= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.605288, -2.337231), {'label': 'LSA_C1/D1_2023-03'});
var p40= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.607987, -2.335425), {'label': 'LSA_C1/D1_2023-04'});
var union17 = ee.FeatureCollection([p37,p38,p39,p40]).set({'name': 'LSA_C1/D1_2023'});

var p41= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.635861, -2.335453), {'label': 'LSA_B4_2021-01'});
var p42= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.634963, -2.334547), {'label': 'LSA_B4_2021-02'});
var union18 = ee.FeatureCollection([p41,p42]).set({'name': 'LSA_B4_2021'});

var p43= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.60549945248736,-2.331748604097494), {'label': 'LSA_B3B_2021-01'});
var union19 = ee.FeatureCollection([p43]).set({'name': 'LSA_B3B_2021'});

var p44= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.606192, -2.3318056), {'label': 'LSA_B3A_2020-01'});
var union20 = ee.FeatureCollection([p44]).set({'name': 'LSA_B3A_2020'});

var p45= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.60799, -2.332712), {'label': 'LSA_B2_2019-01'});
var p46= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.607091, -2.332711), {'label': 'LSA_B2_2019-02'});
var union21 = ee.FeatureCollection([p45,p46]).set({'name': 'LSA_B2_2019'});

var p47= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.606193, -2.330901), {'label': 'LSA_B1_2019-01'});
var p48= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.605294, -2.3309), {'label': 'LSA_B1_2019-02'});
var union22 = ee.FeatureCollection([p47,p48]).set({'name': 'LSA_B1_2019'});

var p49= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.610686, -2.333619), {'label': 'LSA_B1.2/C1.2_2022-01'});
var p50= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.609787, -2.333618), {'label': 'LSA_B1.2/C1.2_2022-02'});
var p51= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.608888, -2.333617), {'label': 'LSA_B1.2/C1.2_2022-01'});
var p52= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.609788, -2.332713), {'label': 'LSA_B1.2/C1.2_2022-02'});
var p53= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.608889, -2.332713), {'label': 'LSA_B1.2/C1.2_2022-02'});
var union23 = ee.FeatureCollection([p49,p50,p51,p52,p53]).set({'name': 'LSA_B1.2/C1.2_2022'});

var p54= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.607083, -2.339946), {'label': 'LSA_A1_2019-01'});
var p55= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.607983, -2.339043), {'label': 'LSA_A1_2019-02'});
var p56= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.607084, -2.339042), {'label': 'LSA_A1_2019-03'});
var union24 = ee.FeatureCollection([p54,p55,p56]).set({'name': 'LSA_A1_2019'});

var points = [union1,union2,union3,union4,union5,union6,union7,union8,union9,union10,
              union11,union12,union13,union14,union15,union16,union17,union18,union19,union20,
              union21,union22,union23,union24];
for (var j =0;j<points.length;j++){
  Map.addLayer(points[j], {color: COLOR.RED}, 'Points');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to accomplish this is to add a property to each feature with the style you want, then use the [`ee.FeatureCollection.style`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-featurecollection-style) method to apply it before adding the collection to the map. Here's a demo with your first two points:

```js
var p1 = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(115.57539510901834, -2.362381045840717), {'label': 'SCM_I5I6_2022-01', 'style': {color: "red"}});
var p2 = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(115.576489, -2.363431), {'label': 'SCM_I5I6_2022-02', 'style': {color: "blue"}});
    
var union1 = ee.FeatureCollection([p1, p2]).set({'name': 'SCM_1516_2022'});

Map.addLayer(union1.style({styleProperty: "style"}), {}, "Points")
```

For collections with a lot of features, it might be more convenient to apply the styles automatically to each feature using a `map`:

```js
var p49 = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(115.610686, -2.333619), {'label': 'LSA_B1.2/C1.2_2022-01'});
var p50 = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(115.609787, -2.333618), {'label': 'LSA_B1.2/C1.2_2022-02'});
var p51 = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(115.608888, -2.333617), {'label': 'LSA_B1.2/C1.2_2022-01'});
var p52 = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(115.609788, -2.332713), {'label': 'LSA_B1.2/C1.2_2022-02'});
var p53 = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(115.608889, -2.332713), {'label': 'LSA_B1.2/C1.2_2022-02'});


var union23 = ee.FeatureCollection([p49,p50,p51,p52,p53])
  .set({'name': 'LSA_B1.2/C1.2_2022'})
  // Assign the same style to each feature in the collection
  .map(function(ft) {return ft.set({style: {color: "aqua"}})})
  
Map.addLayer(union23.style({styleProperty: "style"}), {}, "Points")
```

Note that the `style` method converts the collection to an image, so it's best to only do that when you add the layer to the map, since it would prevent further analysis.

Comment: what if we have more than 1 collection? I tried to demonstrate your second method and tried to combine each collection that you want to color into one command, but on line 21 it cannot be defined. Here is the code: 

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0618d25edc93f223635b769b119df787

do I have to include map.addlayer one by one for each collection?

Comment: You can still loop over your collections to add them all to the map, like in your original code. There were a few typos in your new code. Try this: https://code.earthengine.google.com/38feb7ccba0586eacd440bb876539f0e

Comment: Thank you very much sir for the help and knowledge you provide. Very useful.